# How do I install Lubuntu without a USB or CDROM?

Tags: installation, wubi, lubuntu

The CD-ROM does not work. My PC is very old and does not boot through USB.

I want to install Lubuntu through Windows.  Wubi does not support Lubuntu  (That is what I think).

Is there a program like wubi that can help?

Can you tell me a way to install lubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no lubuntu wubi option.

If you want lubuntu - install the wubi for ubuntu.

Once that is installed you can install the lubuntu-desktop package and then remove the ubuntu packages.

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purelxde

Comment: So, I install Ubuntu . Then I uninstall unity and after install lubuntu ? Could you please explain more? What are the commands?

Comment: Will the experience of Lubuntu be the same as if I installed Lubuntu from scratch ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like[1] Lubuntu will be supported on Wubi in 12.04. If you're willing to wait 2 weeks, that sounds like the easiest solution.

[1] See http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.com/2012/01/wubi-will-support-lubuntu-in-release.html, http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/lubuntu-12-04-news-roundup/, https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/907524/comments/7. Theoretically, you could test a daily build of 12.04 right now if you wanted, though I don't know how stable it would be.

---

**DO NOT INSTALL DAILY/BETA BUILDS UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING AND ARE OK WITH THE IDEA THAT YOUR SYSTEM COULD GO BONKERS OR DATA COULD BE ERASED.**

Comment: Will it be just an update to switch from Beta Lubuntu to Lubuntu ?

Comment: Yes, your beta will turn into release when release gets released.

Comment: no wireless drivers on Lubuntu 12.04!

Comment: Try connecting to a non-wireless network and running a program called like "Additional Drivers."